# SwiftUI: SF symbol in tab item is automatically filled

Tags: swiftui, tabitem, sf-symbols

I notice that tabItem() automatically uses the "fill" version of the SF symbol inside it. See example below. Does anyone know how to show the "non-fill" version of SF symbol in tab item?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Label("Account", systemImage: "dollarsign.square")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Account", systemImage: "dollarsign.square")
                }
            Label("Issues", systemImage: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Issues", systemImage: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I specify "dollarsign.square" and "exclamationmark.triangle" SF symbols, but the actual symbols shown in the tab items are "dollarsign.square.fill" and "exclamationmark.triangle.fill", respectively.

Comment: see this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057749/why-swiftui-tabitem-systemimage-is-filled/70058260#70058260

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll close the question as duplicate.