# Why my SF Icons are automatically filled in Xcode 13 and Ios 15

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios15, xcode13

In a Tabview, I am using SFICON

```
TabView {
NotificationsView()
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "heart")
    }
}
```

In the original SFIcon "heart" is not filled, but when I use it in the code it is filled.
Why do I get this?
How to fix it?

Comment: Even in non-active tab it is filled

Comment: This answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058260/8724386